# Conditions on $f, g, h, k$ for which $f(x)g(y)=h(x)k(y)$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

> **Question:** Precisely what conditions must $f,g,h$, and $k$ satisfy in order that $f(x)g(y)=h(x)k(y)$ for all $x$ and $y$?

I encountered this question while browsing Spivak's *Calculus* (4th, p. 52, prob 18) and also came across [an MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/760411/conditions-on-the-functions-f-g-h-k-if-fxgy-hxky) concerning this exact problem and ways of providing different answers than that of the OP, but my question is more "philosophical":

> **My question:** What other routes (i.e., besides the zero-product law and constant argument) could one reasonably take in answering the original question without anymore instruction?

It is quite obvious that if either $f=0$ or $g=0$ then also either $h=0$ or $k=0$, but that is tee-ball level and it is clear that Spivak is after something more significant, but it is not clear to me at all from the problem statement what that is. The "punchline" is that $g=\alpha k$ and $h=\alpha f$ for some number $\alpha\neq0$ where $\alpha=h(x)/f(x)=g(y)/k(y)$, but how is one to know that *this* is what Spivak is pursuing? (It's a neat fact, of course, but if I were assigned this problem, then I would have simply stated the obvious consequence of the zero-product law and moved on because it is unclear to me what *exact* or *precise*, as Spivak writes, conditions he is going for). Perhaps there are other "neat facts" one could deduce or prove about the functions given the conditions (other than the one referenced above)?

I simply find it odd that the reader is somehow supposed to know that s/he is looking for a way to communicate that there exists a nonzero constant $\alpha$ for which $\frac{g}{k}=\alpha=\frac{h}{f}$, provided that you have nonzero products to begin with. If anyone could speak to this and take a gander as to what Spivak had in mind exactly, then that could potentially be informative.

Comment: To the close voter: I hope it is obvious that I am not asking anyone to "read the author's mind." That would, of course, be nonsense and "opinion-based." I am curious as to how others read the problem statement and where they might pursue things after stating the clear use of the zero-product property.

Answer (score 1):

(*More of a comment, but too long to fit into one.*)

If one of the $\{f, h\}$ functions in $x$ is $\equiv 0$ then one of the $\{g,k\}$ functions in $y$ must be $\equiv 0$ as well.

Otherwise, any zero of $f$ must be a zero of $h$, too, and same for $g,k$ by symmetry. For points $x,y$ where $f(x) \ne 0, g(y) \ne 0$ (which implies that none of the others are zero, either), separating the variables gives $\frac{f(x)}{h(x)} = \frac{k(y)}{g(y)} = \alpha \ne 0$ which must be a constant since $x,y$ are independent variables. Because $f = \alpha \,h, g = \frac{1}{\alpha} \,k$ subsume the case of the pairs having the same zeros, in the end:

- either: at least one of each pairs $\{f, h\}, \{g, k\}$ is $\equiv 0$ identically zero;
- or: there exists a constant $\alpha \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ so that $f(x) = \alpha \,h(x)\,, \;g(y) = \frac{1}{\alpha} \,k(y)$.

In the context of the exercise, I would think that "*precisely*" refers to just discerning and coalescing the sub-cases.